# Having jQuery UI Selectable both as grid and a list in a table

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, overflow, jquery-ui-selectable

I have prepared a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/hoa34crd/) for my question -

[image: screenshot]

I am trying to have [jQuery UI Selectable](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid) in a table with yellow header and footer rows. Once as a grid of numbers in the left cell and then as a list of letters in the right cell.

Also I am trying to have the table occupy both 100% of browser width and height.

That is why I have assigned CSS-properties `width: 100%` and `height: 100vh` to the table and `overflow-y: scroll` to the both selectables.

For some reason however the right scroll is not working, i.e. the whole list of letters is displayed and thus blows up the table height.

**TLDR:**

- Numbers/Letters lists should have same height and be scrollable
- Yellow header/footer should be visible at top/bottom of browser window

Here is my code -

**Javascript:**

```
  $(function() {
    $("#selectable1").selectable();
    $("#selectable2").selectable();
  });
```

**CSS:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2 bgcolor="yellow">Header1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ol id="selectable1">
        <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
      </ol>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ol id="selectable2">
        <li class="ui-state-default">A</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">B</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">C</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">D</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">E</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">F</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">G</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">H</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">I</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">J</li>
      </ol>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2 bgcolor="yellow">Footer1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#selectable1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#selectable2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING? */
}

#selectable1 li,
#selectable2 li {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The background for my question is that I am trying to create a card game with playing tables on the left and list of players in the lobby on the right -

[image: game screenshot]

Comment: It's not clear what you need help with. The Selectable or the CSS?

Comment: The CSS, is there please a way to set the digits and the letters cell to same (and maximal) height?

Comment: Do you need to retain the Table structure? If not, I would move each to a DIV and you can then more easily address the CSS issues.

Comment: I would like to move away from the html TABLE, but I don't understand how to have both header and footer TRs onscreen and then the letters/digits area. I am just not sure how to do that with DIVs

Comment: I would like the header/footer TR to take as liitle space as possible (but still be visible). And the letters/digits TR take as much space as possible and be scrollable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

To support IE 11, you can update your CSS to include `-ms-grid` specific styles and it should work but again you might have to test it thoroughly:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#selectable1").selectable();
  $("#selectable2").selectable();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background: yellow;
  -ms-grid-row: 1; /* for IE */
}

.footer {
  background: yellow;
  -ms-grid-row: 3; /* for IE */
}

div.table {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
  /* for IE */
  display: -ms-grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 20px 1fr 20px;
}

div.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 140px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  /* for IE */
  display: -ms-grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 140px;
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
}

div.container div {
  overflow: auto;
}

div.container div.column1 {
    -ms-grid-column: 1; /* for IE */
}

div.container div.column2 {
    -ms-grid-column: 2; /* for IE */
}

#selectable1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex: 1;
}

#selectable2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#selectable1 li,
#selectable2 li {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">Header1</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column1">
      <ol id="selectable1">
        <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      <ol id="selectable2">
        <li class="ui-state-default">A</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">B</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">C</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">D</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">E</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">F</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">G</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">H</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">I</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">J</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer1</div>
</div>
```

You should be able to use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) to achieve what you want if you are willing to replace table with them:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#selectable1").selectable();
  $("#selectable2").selectable();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background: yellow;
}

div.table {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

div.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 140px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.container div {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#selectable1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex: 1;
}

#selectable2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#selectable1 li,
#selectable2 li {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">Header1</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <ol id="selectable1">
        <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ol id="selectable2">
        <li class="ui-state-default">A</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">B</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">C</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">D</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">E</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">F</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">G</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">H</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">I</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">J</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works just perfectly except in the IE browser (which I know I didn't mention). Please let me wait few days and accept the answer. Why is the `overflow: auto;` needed?

Comment: `overflow: auto` is needed to ensure that container div doesn't expand fully and display scrollbars when content height/width exceeds width/height of it's container. About IE, do you mean edge or IE 11? CSS3 Grid are not supported in IE but are supported in edge. I have updated answer to include css for IE 11.

Comment: Yes, now it works with IE 11 just perfectly, thank you. I still have to support IE because my card game is for Russian users, some still using Win 7.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/uro3b2ps/17/

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">Header1</div>
  <div class="content">
    <ol id="selectable1">
      <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
    </ol>
    <ol id="selectable2">
      <li class="ui-state-default">A</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">B</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">C</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">D</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">E</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">F</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">G</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">H</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">I</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">J</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <td colspan=2 bgcolor="yellow">Footer1</td>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header,
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#selectable1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  float: left;
}

#selectable2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#selectable1 li,
#selectable2 li {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

There are lots of other ways to do this. `inline-block` is another way of the many ways to block something but allow space after it for other elements. `float` is also another way.

Basically, you have to set a height for the list element and this will create a scrollbar when there is overflow.

**Updated**

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/uro3b2ps/21/

```
#selectable2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**Update 2**

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/uro3b2ps/25/

This uses jQuery to dynamically set the height based on the Window.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately the yellow footer is not visible, the #selectable2 seems to push it way down. I was thinking first maybe a jsfiddle issue, but after saving your code to a separate HTML file the issue persists: the footer is not visible.

Comment: You have updated your answer by setting a fixed `height: 200px;` for `#selectabled2` but this is not a solution, the footer should be at the bottom of the screen (that is why I am trying to use `height: 100vh;`for the parent table). In your updated jsfiddle, the yellow footer is near the screen middle

Comment: @AlexanderFarber that was not clear from your post. Updated answer.